# NS server updated, but A record pulled from old nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, a-record, ns-record, domains

I use Amazon AWS Route 53 as both my DNS and Nameserver.
I want to use Wix as my name server.
I've updated my NS record on AWS Route to point to the Wix name server.

It's been 72 hours, and I think the change has propagated. I visit https://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS/myexampledomain.com and the NS record reported is the new NS record, i.e., ns8.wixdns.net and ns9.wixdns.net

However, when I use whatsmydns.net to look up my A record, I get the A record specified by my old name server, and not the new name server.

It's my understanding that, when someone visits myexampledomain.com, they first go to the .com TLD, which gives them the address of the name server. The requester than asks the name server what the IP address is, and the IP address is looked up from the A record.

So, my question is, how is it possible that the old A Record is being used, if the NS record has changed?

[update]

The domain is starbutter.com
I was able to circumvent the issue by changing the CNAME and A record on my original name server.

Apparently the NIC name server has the old name server, but the Authoritative name server is the new name server.

```
# The NIC name server:
www.starbutter.com@h.gtld-servers.net.:
starbutter.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns-54.awsdns-06.com.

# The Authoritative name server:
www.starbutter.com@ns8.wixdns.net.:
www.starbutter.com. 3600    IN  CNAME   www52.wixdns.net.
```

You can verify this by looking up www.starbutter.com at https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=www.starbutter.com&type=&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=nic&nameservers=

Please explain the difference between the NIC name server and the Authoritative name server, and also tell me if I need to do something to update the NIC name server.

Comment: This is probably a problem with glue records. If you give the real domain, we can figure out what you did wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "as both my DNS and Nameserver"? DNS and nameserver are the same thing. If you're using Route 53, they probably require you to use Amazon's DNS, because the failover is implemented as part of the DNS service.

Answer (score 0):

You might check internally set glue records.  I just ran a dig across the starbutter.com domain name and see WiX as the NS/SOA and WIX was the responding DNS when querying www.starbutter.com (result of CNAME to www52.wixdns.net, etc).

So it sounds as if you may have an internal record pointing the NS for starbutter.com to the old Amazon name servers (long TTL was ruled out when you changed the record at Amazon and it reflected as expected).

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `dig +trace www.example.com` to see how your names are being resolved.  This should help identify where the issue is.

When changing you nameservers you need to update the records at your Domain registrar to point to the new nameservers.  The DNS lookups generally are done like this (using www.example.com with ns1.example.com as name server for example.com):

- `.` (root) returns the names serves for `.com`.
- `.com` returns nameservers (`ns1.example.com` ...) for `example.com` from domain registrars data.  This is not authoritative.
- `ns1.example.com` returns authoritative responses for `example.com` assuming sub domains haven't been delegated to other name serves.
- `ns1.example.com` returns an authoritative A record for `www.example.com`.

Any or all of these responses may be cached by the name server you are using.  The first lookup is most likely a cached lookup.

You may want to change the NS records for your domain on the old nameservers point to the new nameservers.  This will add an additional lookup, but may get the correct nameservers responding.